# Sproutcore: adding a custom stylesheet or script

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I just can't seem to find a good tutorial on this.
It's simple: I want to link a stylesheet / js file to the HEAD section of my application.

I found where the index.html file is (in tmp/build/static/my_project/en/current) and I can make changes to it, but I think this is the wrong way.

Answer (score 5):

Ok I found a way:

in the Buildfile of your app add this:

```
:styles => "resources/styles.css"
```

and put your stylesheet into the resources dir, where your main_page.js and loading.rhtml is